# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

```
 I am new in vue with laravel. I need to implement vue-form-wizard in project.I am trying to implement vue form wizard with laravel and get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined**.  Please suggest.
 Laravel 5.5 with vue 2.5
 install error occur when page load.

 I have not install any external package.
 I follow this link https://jsfiddle.net/CristiJ/bt5dhqtf/1119/
 This is the documentation of vue form wizard and implement vuelidate form wizard but not implement.
http://vuejs.creative-tim.com/vue-form-wizard/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/?id=form-wizard-props
```

**This is the main app.js file which is mount with id **app****
app.js

```
 import VueFormWizard from 'vue-form-wizard';
    import 'vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css';
    Vue.use(VueFormWizard);

    Vue.use(window.vuelidate)
    const {
      required,
      minLength,
      email
    } = window.validators
    Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
```

MyTemplate.vue

This is the component file which are define in resource/assets/component

```
    <template>
    <div>
    <form-wizard shape="square" color="#3498db">
      <tab-content title="Personal details" icon="ti-user" :before-change="()=>validateStep('step1')">
        <step1 ref="step1" @on-validate="mergePartialModels"></step1>
      </tab-content>
      <tab-content title="Additional Info" icon="ti-settings" :before-change="()=>validateStep('step2')">
        <step2 ref="step2" @on-validate="mergePartialModels"></step2>
      </tab-content>
      <tab-content title="Last step" icon="ti-check">
        Here is your final model:
       <pre>{{finalModel}}</pre>
      </tab-content>
    </form-wizard>
  </div>
    </template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
const {
  required,
  minLength,
  email
} = window.validators
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)

Vue.component('step1', {
  template: `<div>
          <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': $v.firstName.$error }">
            <label >First name</label>
            <input class="form-control" v-model.trim="firstName" @input="$v.firstName.$touch()">
             <span class="help-block" v-if="$v.firstName.$error && !$v.firstName.required">First name is required</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': $v.lastName.$error }">
            <label>Last name</label>
            <input class="form-control" v-model.trim="lastName" @input="$v.lastName.$touch()">
             <span class="help-block" v-if="$v.lastName.$error && !$v.lastName.required">Last name is required</span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': $v.email.$error }">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" v-model.trim="email" @input="$v.email.$touch()">
            <span class="help-block" v-if="$v.email.$error && !$v.email.required">Email is required</span>
            <span class="help-block" v-if="$v.email.$error && !$v.email.email">This is not a valid email!</span>
          </div>
        </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: ''
    }
  },
  validations: {
    firstName: {
      required
    },
    lastName: {
      required
    },
    email: {
      required,
      email
    },
    form: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email']
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.$v.form.$touch();
      var isValid = !this.$v.form.$invalid
      this.$emit('on-validate', this.$data, isValid)
      return isValid
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('step2', {
  template: `<div>
          <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': $v.country.$error }">
            <label >Country</label>
            <select class="form-control" v-model.trim="country" @input="$v.country.$touch()">
              <option>USA</option>
                       <option>United Kingdom</option>
                        <option>France</option>
            </select>
             <span class="help-block" v-if="$v.country.$error && !$v.country.required">Country is required</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': $v.city.$error }">
            <label>City</label>
            <input class="form-control" v-model.trim="city" @input="$v.city.$touch()">
             <span class="help-block" v-if="$v.city.$error && !$v.city.required">City is required</span>
          </div>
        </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      country: '',
      city: ''
    }
  },
  validations: {
    country: {
      required
    },
    city: {
      required
    },
    form: ['country', 'city']
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.$v.form.$touch();
      var isValid = !this.$v.form.$invalid
      this.$emit('on-validate', this.$data, isValid)
      return isValid
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    finalModel: {},
  },
  methods: {
    validateStep(name) {
      var refToValidate = this.$refs[name];
      return refToValidate.validate();
    },
    mergePartialModels(model, isValid){
      if(isValid){
      // merging each step model into the final model
       this.finalModel = Object.assign({},this.finalModel, model)
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

I am follow the steps according to documentation but getting error. Please help and thanks  in advance.

I am new in vue with laravel. I need to implement vue-form-wizard in project.I am trying to implement vue form wizard with laravel and get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined**.  Please suggest.
     Laravel 5.5 with vue 2.5
     install error occur when page load.

```
 I have not install any external package.
 I follow this link https://jsfiddle.net/CristiJ/bt5dhqtf/1119/
 This is the documentation of vue form wizard and implement vuelidate form wizard but not implement.
http://vuejs.creative-tim.com/vue-form-wizard/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/?id=form-wizard-props
```

Comment: You have a javascript error when you are calling `install` property  on undefined object.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing vue form wizrd package internally call install methods.

Comment: In that case you did not setup your form wizard correctly.

Comment: Ok, I am uninstall and then install again.

Comment: still same error.

Comment: explain what u have done exactly add codes or commands